# Trying to UNION the statements using loop in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on an app where I have a table called `reps` who has many `dealers` from `dealers` table and then again a `dealer` has many `subdealers` from `subdealers` table - I have foreign key named `dealer_id` from which I can find `subdealers` but the problem is I have `dealers` in an array which may increase or decrease depending on the `rep` which they belongs to

This is what I am trying to achieve but going nowhere

```
    foreach ($dealers as $dealer) {
        $subdealers = DB::table('subdealers')->where('dealer_id', '=', $dealer->id);
    }
```

Then iterate the `$subdealers` to get the value

But I know it's not possible as I am doing what I want is to `UNION` all results into one array and then iterate them in blade

How is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though it is too late, but it may help anyone else.
Here is what I did in same situation.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($dealers as $dealer) {
    $q = DB::table('subdealers')->where('dealer_id', '=', $dealer->id);
    if($i < 1){
        $subdealers = $q;
    }else{
        $subdealers->union($q);
    }
    $i++
}
$subdealers = $subdealers->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the query ( **`get()`** ). Try this code :

```
foreach ($dealers as $dealer) {
    $subdealers = DB::table('subdealers')
        ->where('dealer_id', '=', $dealer->id)
        ->get();
}
```

Refer to the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#unions)

Comment: Actually this is not the problem here - what I want is to get all of these subdealers in an array object so I can iterate it in blade but the above would give me just one entry which would be written at the last loop